# How to fix the jumping Background at Cardoverlays?

Tags: background, transition, overlay, card

Hi all I have created a card overlay but when I hover over the card and stay in the top area the background jumps to where the mouse is and wobbles there. What is wrong with my approach?

here the Page link inc. anker:
http://wp-impuls.pritumble-test.de/#aktuelleMeldungen

```
/* Beitragsuebersicht */
.pt__overlay-beitragsuebersicht {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(3, 29, 67, 0.752);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: height 1s;
}
.pt__overlay-beitragsuebersicht:hover {
    height: 30%;
}
.pt__beitragsuebersicht-header {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 

    a {
        color:white;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
}
.pt__betragsuebersicht-seperator {
    position: absolute;
    content: url(../../../uploads/2023/svg/seperator-betraege.svg);
    width: 34%;
    bottom: 14%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* END Beitragsuebersicht */
```